# Как скомпилировать libcurl вместе с программой, в один файл под mips, arm?

Tags: linux, curl, embedded, кросс-компиляция

Тулчейн: http://uclibc.org/downloads/binaries/0.9.30.1/cross-compiler-mips.tar.bz2

libcurl: https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.20.0.tar.bz2

хост система: debian stable amd64

Конфигурация libcurl: `./configure CFLAGS=-static`

Сама компиляция libcurl проходит успешно. В папках src и lib появляются объектные файлы. В папке src так же появляется файл curl, однако:

`$ qemu-mips src/curl 
/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0: No such file or directory`

Компилил под amd64 соответствующим тулчейном, тоже самое:

`$ ./src/curl 
/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0: No such file or directory`

Если указать путь до этой библиотеки то пишет что файла src/curl не существует.

Собственно сам src/curl мне не нужен. Мне нужно самописную программу использующую libcurl скомпилировать под mips, arm в один файл без зависимостей(статической линковкой). Собственно как это сделать?

P.S. libcurl старой версии т.к. последняя у меня не компилируется.

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас хост система на glibc и потому она ulibc не видит.

Comment: В вопросе напишите как компилируете, с какими опциями

Comment: Да хост на glibc.

Comment: а компилите пол ulibc. укажите путь для LD к ulibc - будет запускаться. Статическая линковка у вас не получилась или не пробовали?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Я не знаю какие libcurl файлы статически линковать с моей программой.

Comment: попробуйте получить их через pkgconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Флаги для статической линковки можно получить через pkg-config.

```
pkg-config --static --libs libcurl

-lcurl -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lssh2 -lpsl -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lz
```

Используйте pkg-config в окружении тулчейна при кросс-компиляции.

Если файл слинковался очень большой, то можно его подрезать `strip`

Comment: переконфигурировал со своим --prefix=, сделал make install(до этого не делал,думал объектные файлы mips-gcc скормить), и сделал компиляцию с ключами -I -L -l -static, всё собралось в один статичный файл. Интересно что файл работает под mips и под amd64 хотя скомпилен под mips. Почему так? Эмуляция процессором(как x86-32)?

Проблемы по сути вообще не было, просто я не понимал принципа сборки.

Comment: если стоит пакет binformats от qemu, то линукс автоматом подсовывает куэму